# How to whether Primeng Turbo Table is fully rendered in Angular 7?

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular7, primeng-turbotable

I'm working on a kind of requirement wherein I need to know whether the table is fully rendered; if so then I can call the other methods which will do some processing on the rendered table.

Is there any way through which we can determine that the PrimeNN TurboTable has completely rendered?

Thanks for your help.